# Is it possible to add an html class to the tables generated by phpMyEdit?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to use Bootstrap 3 to style the tables created by PHPMyEdit (Bootstra 3 requires a "table" class added to the table to style), but I can't find a way to add a class to the table it creates.  I could write my own styles to target its auto-added classes, but I'd rather not do it that way.

phpmyedit for those unfamiliar: http://www.phpmyedit.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave this open in case anyone knows of a way to do it with phpmyedit, but I ended up just using jquery to add the class on doc ready.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the `.table` Bootstrap CSS properties to the PHPMyEdit `table` class ?
(instead of adding the `.table` class on the `table` element with jQuery...)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to reply so late, but I somewhat solved this issue by copying the styles used by Bootstrap over into our stylesheet.

Adding the **!important** parameter ensures that these general classes are used instead of the inbuilt page styles.

Here is the css that resulted from that transition, keep in mind it's not complete.

```
    table.pme-main {
    margin-top:10px;
    padding: 8px !important;
    line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
    vertical-align: top !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd !important;
    width: 75% !important;
    max-width: 1920px !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color:black !important;
}

td.pme-navigation-0,
td.pme-navigation-1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
th.pme-header {
    border: 0px !important;
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd !important;
    background: #F8F8F8 !important;
    color:black !important;
}
td.pme-key-0,
td.pme-value-0,
td.pme-help-0,
td.pme-navigation-0,
td.pme-cell-0,
td.pme-key-1,
td.pme-value-1,
td.pme-help-0,
td.pme-navigation-1,
td.pme-cell-1,
td.pme-sortinfo,
td.pme-filter {
    border: 0px !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd !important;
    padding: 3px;
}
```